# What does "if you were already set for life" mean?

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

From [this blog post](http://www.stevepavlina.com/blog/2006/05/how-to-make-money-from-your-blog/), the author writes:

> What’s your passion?  What would you blog about if you were already
>   set for life?

I don't quite understand — what meaning is the author trying to convey? Can someone explain that sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Set for life](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_for_life)* means that you will never have to work for a living.  Your finances are already *[set](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set#Adjective) in place for the rest of your life*.

In the specific context of blogging to earn money, the question is: "What would you blog about if you did not need to earn any money while blogging?"